# Emacs on HiDPI screen renders unreadable fonts Arch Linux

Tags: arch-linux, emacs

I just installed Emacs on Arch Linux for my MBP 13 Retina but the fonts and menus are super small. However I don't care about the menus since I'm disabling them but I do need to know how to scale the fonts to look nice on [HiDPI](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/HiDPI).

Comment: did you check with `xdpyinfo` that the resolution in dots per inch is correct?

Comment: I dont have any issues in other programs. It is only in emacs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an answer over on [emacs.stackexchange](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/10439/8633) that links to the [appropriate paragraph](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/SetFonts#GloballyChangingFont) in the emacs wiki. Simply edit your init file, usually `~/.emacs` for gnu emacs, and add the lines

```
(add-to-list 'default-frame-alist '(font .  FONT ))
(set-face-attribute 'default t :font  FONT )
```

where you need to replace `FONT` by the name and size of your chosen font, eg `"Droid Sans Mono-30"`. There's lots of other good info on that page.